# Nsight for VS 2010 will not be installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nsight

Well, I got VS 2008, VS 2010 and even VS 2012 on my PC. I downloaded CUDA 5.0 SDK and installed it. But when I installing Nsight appears this 
[image]

How can I install it properly?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio Express 2008?

Comment: @talonmies yep. but I tried CUDA wizard already if you want to recomend it :)

Comment: You cannot use the express versions of VS with nsight

Comment: @RobertCrovella oh why? should i try eclipse then? which version btw?

Comment: The express versions of VS do not support the plug-in mechanism that nsight VSE uses.  There is no CUDA support for eclipse on Windows.  Nsight EE runs on Linux only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the express versions of VS with nsight. The express versions of VS do not support the plug-in mechanism that nsight VSE uses. There is no CUDA support for eclipse on Windows. Nsight EE runs on Linux only.